# Como inserir uma nova chave associado dentro de Array Multidimensional em PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach

O array possui a seguinte estrutura abaixo:

```
    $array = [
        [['total_arrematado' => 27, 'id' => 5],['total_arrematado' => 10, 'id' => 7]],
        [['total_arrematado' => 50, 'id' => 8],['total_arrematado' => 60, 'id' => 15]]
    ];



Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_arrematado] => 27
                    [id] => 5
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [total_arrematado] => 10
                    [id] => 7
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_arrematado] => 50
                    [id] => 8
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [total_arrematado] => 60
                    [id] => 15
                )
        )
)
```

Como seria possível criar uma nova chave dinamicamente dentro de cada array para ficar com a seguinte estrutura:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_arrematado] => 27
                    [id] => 5
                    [total_itens] => 100
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [total_arrematado] => 10
                    [id] => 7
                    [total_itens] => 100
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_arrematado] => 50
                    [id] => 8
                    [total_itens] => 100
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [total_arrematado] => 60
                    [id] => 15
                    [total_itens] => 100
                )
        )
)
```

Já tentei com dois foreachs, mas não funciona:

```
   foreach ($array as $key => $linha1) {
        foreach ($linha1 as $k => $r) {
            $linha1[$k]['total_itens'] = 100;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é um `array` que possui duas posições e cada posição desse `array` contem mais dois `array`, então tem que ser dois `for`, isso resolve seu problema:

```
<?php

$array = [
  [['total_arrematado' => 27, 'id' => 5], ['total_arrematado' => 10, 'id' => 7]],
  [['total_arrematado' => 50, 'id' => 8], ['total_arrematado' => 60, 'id' => 15]]
];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  for ($j = 0; $j < count($array[$i]); $j++) {
    $array[$i][$j]['total_itens'] = 100;
  }
}
```

---

Saída:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["total_arrematado"]=>
      int(27)
      ["id"]=>
      int(5)
      ["total_itens"]=>     
      int(100)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["total_arrematado"]=>
      int(10)
      ["id"]=>
      int(7)
      ["total_itens"]=>
      int(100)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["total_arrematado"]=>
      int(50)
      ["id"]=>
      int(8)
      ["total_itens"]=>
      int(100)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["total_arrematado"]=>
      int(60)
      ["id"]=>
      int(15)
      ["total_itens"]=>
      int(100)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: novic, perfeito!!! Valeu